# I can't use system.windows.control namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I'm trying to add a reference to the namespace `System.Windows.Controls` in a library project, but i can't find it in the list. Does anybody know what is going on? i'm using 4.0. I want to add `system.window.controls.dll` but the library is not complete, how can i make it complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look for this `System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll` assembly. In this assembly, there is the namespace you are looking for.

In general, a namespace and it's types may be in an assembly with different name than the namespace name.

Comment: thanks ,Christos.you are right .i solve this through 3 step as you said  Here are the steps:           

Go to add reference
Go to the .NET tab
Add the PresentationFramework component

Comment: ,sorry mate.not enough reputation so cant vote you up .Lol...

Comment: @wenluowang not a problem at all.